# “needs more focus”: Significantly different from former “too broad” close reason

Tags: bug, close-reasons

The [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493600/manufacturing-of-smart-locks-and-smart-bulb)

> I am planning to start manufacturing of smart locks and smart bulb that are integrated with tuya application. How should I make a circuit?

was pretty rightfully (imho, but I think most will agree) closed as "too broad".

Sadly, what *used to be* "too broad", and thus a sensible close reason for this very clear case of a question that can't be sensibly answered within the format of the site, lately got reworked to

> **Needs more focus**
>   This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

which is fundamentally different. OP might just ask a single question (or the fact that they ask two, related, questions isn't the problem at all), but that question might still be parsecs too broad.

Thus, this being a rather large non-Stackoverflow StackExchange community, can we get our "too broad" close reason back? The current state of affairs is actually a bug, as it simply doesn't cover a large percentage of the inanswerable questions.

---

I've asked a similar question on meta.dsp, but they are a much smaller community and might view that differently.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a network-wide problematic. It would be better asked on the main meta. Good luck.

Comment: We are held captive by the powers that be, your odds of changing this are not good

Comment: I agree totally. I was wondering why it was changed. It would still be the most sensible reason to close most of the low-quality questions cluttering in the queue.